# permanent firefox 4 application tabs?

Tags: firefox, browser, browser-tabs

Is there any way to make the FF4 application tabs "permanent"?

Comment: How do you mean "permanent"? They are permanent, at least for me. Once I've set a tab as app tab FF always starts with that tab pinned.

Comment: i keep having them not come back, sometimes when restarting they aren't there, or i have to restore my previous session to get them back, and even sometimes there is no session to restore and i get nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I remember now that I had this problem with a couple of the latest B13 nightlies. So if you haven't already done it, uninstall current version and install FF4 RC. Hopefully that will solve the problem.